# React setTimeout takes place immediately not after 3 seconds

Tags: reactjs

I will try explain this problem(solved) one more time for exercise post writing on stackoverflow .I wanted to after logged in correctly on my website ,display text that says the user has logged in correctly and after 3 seconds Redirect on page with posts.My code Redirected immediately .Importants things of my old code :

```
const Register = () => {
...
const goLoginPage = () => {
 return <div>setTimeout(() => {<Redirect to="/" />}, 3000);</div>;
};
...
return(
  {isError == false && (
    <div> 
      <p className="successMessage">Logged in</p>
      {goLoginPage()}
   </div>
)}
)
```

I hope my post is better now .Sincerely

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6422) is an example of how to implement delayed redirect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is using state, which will tell the render method, if it should render Redirect component.

Example:

```
const YourComponent = () => {
  ... 
  const [timeToRedirect, setTimeToRedirect] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => setTimeToRedirect(true), 3000)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      ...
      {timeToRedirect && <Redirect to="/" />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can init state like

```
  state = {
        delyaRedirect: false
    }

setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({ delyaRedirect: true })
    }, 3000);
```

and use conditional render

```
{this.state.delyaRedirect && <Redirect to={'/'} />}
```